# How can I tell if this independence system forms a matroid?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, independence, combinatorial-proofs, matroids

Let $(V,E)$ be a graph and consider a system $f$ of subsets of $V$ with $U\in f \mbox{ and }  \forall u,v\in U$ we have $(u,v)\notin E$. This, $(V,f)$ is trivially an independence system, but how can I further decide whether it is a matroid?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the graph with vertices $u$, $v$, and $w$ and edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,w)$:

```
*---*---*
u   v   w
```

Let $f=\left\{\{v\},\{u,w\}\right\}$. Does $f$ have the augmentation property (independent set exchange property)?

Comment: so i consider an f which has two vertices, v and which other? i am confused because it contains the edge (u,w) as well as a vertex. should f={{v},{w}} as that would include two vertices that are not connected by an arc?

Comment: No, $f$ contains two **sets** of vertices, the set $\{v\}$ and the set $\{u,w\}$ — **not** the edge $\{u,w\}$. I don’t like to use $(u,v)$ for an edge, because it suggests that we’re talking about a directed edge (from $u$ to $v$), but I’ll change to your notation to avoid confusion.

Comment: So for the example above i come to the conclusion that i am unable to find an e in f0-f1 such that f0Ue is in f?

Comment: @user3486373: Correct: $f$ does not have the augmentation property and is therefore not a matroid.

Comment: One doesn't even need to check the augmentation property for this example. If $f$ is the set of facets (a.k.a. bases) of a matroid then every element of $f$ must have the same cardinality. In the language of abstract simplicial complexes, every matroid is pure. The independence system in this example has one facet of size one and another of size two, so it can't be a matroid.